# port and ip for remote procedure call unix

Tags: c, linux, rpc

I am making a server-client program using RPC (Remote Procedure Call). The clients send to the server three numbers, the server makes the sum of the numbers and if it is greater than the current sum than the server sends back to the client those three numbers. But I want the server to send back the port and the IP of the client and I don't know how to do that. Is there an easy way to solve this?

Here's my code:

headerrpc.h

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <rpc/xdr.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PROGRAM_EXEC ((u_long)0x40000000)
#define VERSIUNE_EXEC ((u_long)1)
#define EXEC_ADD ((u_long)2)

typedef struct Data{
  short a;
  short b;
  short c;
  u_short port;
}Data;

int xdr_Data(XDR* xdr, Data* d){
  if(xdr_short(xdr,&(d->a)) == 0) return 0;
  if(xdr_short(xdr,&(d->b)) == 0) return 0;
  if(xdr_short(xdr,&(d->c)) == 0) return 0;
  if(xdr_short(xdr,&(d->port)) == 0) return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Server

```
#include "headerrpc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Data* data;

Data* add(Data* d){
  static int sum = -32000;
  //Data* data = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
  if((d->a + d->b + d->c) > sum)
  {

    sum = d->a + d->b + d->c;
    data->a = d->a;
    data->b = d->b;
    data->c = d->c;
    data->port = data->port;
    printf("It was found a greater sum %d\n");
    return data;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("The sum of the given numbers is not greater than the current sum\n");
    return data;
  }
}

main(){
  data = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
  registerrpc(PROGRAM_EXEC, VERSIUNE_EXEC, EXEC_ADD, add, xdr_Data, xdr_Data);
  svc_run();
}
```

Client

```
#include "headerrpc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
  Data d;
  Data* r = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
  int suma;
  printf("Client\n");

  int a, b, c;
  printf("Type the first number: ");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  printf("Type the second number: ");
  scanf("%d",&b);
  printf("Type the third number: ");
  scanf("%d",&c);  

  d.a = a;
  d.b = b;
  d.c = c;
  d.port = serv_addr.sin_port;

  callrpc("localhost",PROGRAM_EXEC, VERSIUNE_EXEC,EXEC_ADD,(xdrproc_t)xdr_Data,(char*)&d,(xdrproc_t)xdr_Data,(char*)r);

  printf("The numbers with the greater sum are: %d, %d, %d\n", r->a,r->b,r->c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default server routine actually takes a second parameter `struct svc_req *rqstp`, from which the IP address of the client can be determined.

so your add function definition should look like:

```
Data* add(Data* d, struct svc_req *rqstp) {
```

You can determine the client's ip address from the `rqstp->rq_xprt->xp_raddr.sin_addr` member, ditto the port from the `rqstp->rq_xprt->xp_raddr.sin_port` member.

Because you're using `registerrpc`, that means that the service will only be available over `UDP` and won't be available over IPv6, which means the address is a 32bit value which is trivial to return.

I don't have enough experience of RPC over IPv6 to be able to give an answer that I know will work in that situation.